# Changes in meaning if indefinite article is added

Tags: articles

How the meaning of this sentence changes if an indefinite article is added?

> The terms of the contract are clearly giving some people pause.

Vs

> The terms of the contract are clearly giving some people a pause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the article breaks the idiom.

"Give someone pause" is an idiom that means "cause someone to think carefully or hesitate before doing something." (lexico)

"Give someone a pause" is not an idiom, and if it means anything, it means "give someone a short break"